# Is there a way detecting page size of particular webpages programmatically?

Tags: google-tag-manager, server-side-rendering, page-size

We have e-commerce web application. There are lots of products listed. (When we search with space in search box, and press search button,  all products are listed)  For each product , I want to get Product detail page and detect page size for each url of product.

This is other subject , In fact I just need to get page size in spesific URL programmatically.

[image: Page Size to be detected in chrome]

Comment: If you are looking to get window heights and widths, you could create parameters and pass that data along to GA as a custom dimension. Here is something that might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window

Comment: I am not looking for window height or width.

Comment: My bad, I read page size as window size; not how many MBs it is. Looking around the web at this, there appears to be some APIs that might be available to get this information. However, trying through console for me didn't work. Researching PerformanceResourceTiming.transferSize might prove beneficial: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming/transferSize

Comment: Thansk for your answers, it should be from server-side